# .htaccess (mod_rewrite) php redirection does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Disclaimer :** know nothing about mode rewriting

I'v a simple .htacces the code is below:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### hide .php extension snippet    
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L,NE]

## add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I've some internal redirection, if user successfull logged in it should redirect to another folder's index file. it was work fine before adding this `.htaccess` file.

This is how i'm redirecting :

```
function redirectTO($url = null){
    if($url != null){
        header("Location:{$url}");
        exit();
    }
}

redirectTO('agent/index.php');
```

**EDIT:** Redirection has stopped working after adding that mode rewrite code. i don't know if i need all of that code I've copied from a another stack overflow post. if you think some of the .htaccess code is irrelevant please feel free to advise on that too.

By the way I've also added this `<base href="/" />` line aswell in my html in `<head>` section. I don't know what is the issue seems to be any Idea?

Comment: **does not work** Could you be more explicit ? Otherwise, we can't help you

Comment: Ok @JustinIurman this redirection has stopped work after that htaccess  file.. btw let me edit my post as well

Comment: What was the reason for adding the .htaccess file in the first place? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Try use this code but u have to put your folder name after

RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/ in 9th line.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
    # slashes.
    # If your page resides at
    # http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
    # then use
    # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
    RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/CodeIgniter/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: In your Code put your folder name where you install the codeigniter in 4th line.

Comment: let me try that @Kakshak

Comment: Have you write your folder name after "RewriteBase /" ?